# Nested JSON with root element not having key and it is varying

Tags: json, nested, key, gson

I have a unique requirement where i need to construct a JSON as below.

```
{  
  "XXXMonitoring/DC/EVN/DBNAME":{  
    "t":123456777,
    "s":{  
      "CAPTURE":{  
        "c":100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where the root element "XXXMonitoring/DC/EVN/DBNAME" contains "/" in between as it represents a path. I tried with GSON to have nested java but not sure how i can represent "XXXMonitoring/DC/EVN/DBNAME" from my Java object.

Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what are you asking...

But sollidus (/) is escaped by backslash (\) to be sure that the browser won’t mistake it for the closing script tag

when you need to use that key, you can remove backslash with String.replaceAll() method

json.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", "");

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string can be constructed without POJO class using the below code.

If the JSON structure is same and only values will change for the keys, you can replace the hard coded values with variables and convert this into an utility method. The utility method can be reused to generate the JSON string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        JsonObject jsonRootObject = new JsonObject();
        JsonObject jsonFirstLevelObject = new JsonObject();

        // t property
        jsonFirstLevelObject.addProperty("t", 123456777);

        JsonObject jsonCaptureObject = new JsonObject();
        JsonObject jsonCObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonCObject.addProperty("c", 100);
        jsonCaptureObject.add("CAPTURE", jsonCObject);

        // s property
        jsonFirstLevelObject.add("s", jsonCaptureObject);

        jsonRootObject.add("XXXMonitoring/DC/EVN/DBNAME", jsonFirstLevelObject);

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(jsonRootObject));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a library called [GsonPath](https://github.com/LachlanMcKee/gsonpath) which might suit your needs. The aim of the library is to provide an annotation processor that generates the boilerplate code to help simplify the POJO you need to write.

By using the library you can write a POJO similar to the following:

```
@AutoGsonAdapter(rootField = "XXXMonitoring/DC/EVN/DBNAME")
public class SamplePojo {
    int t;

    @SerializedName("s.CAPTURE.c")
    int sCapture;
}
```

Then all you need to do in your `gson` object is to register a special `TypeAdapterFactory`

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(GsonPath.createTypeAdapterFactory());
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

The documentation within the [library](https://github.com/LachlanMcKee/gsonpath) is faily comprehensive, let me know if you have any problems!